# How do I access my website (IIS) from the internet?

Tags: iis

I have installed IIS.  I have browsed to my website on IIS using the 'Browse *:80 (http)' link in IIS.  This navigates to `http://localhost`.  That link is only going to work on my own machine.

I don't care about my IP address changing (I'm going to show my website for a few hours max every now and then so can update it and resend the link as and when required).

How do I make my website accessible to the internet?  What url should I use `http://82.11.220.212` (where 82.11.220.212 is the IP of my computer)?  Do I need to disable firewalls / add exceptions to my modem / router?

Comment: I don't need a registered web server and I'm sure I don't need a domain name (http://212.58.241.131 is one way to access bbc website).  I have access to a copy of windows server if that helps but I think I should be able to expose my website just using windows 7 and IIS.

Comment: Thanks Pablo, I have a desktop so I'll just plug that directly into my broadband and see what happens.  and I would just use the url http://myip     nothing after that correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to make sure that your broadband provider has given you a static IP (there is sometimes an extra charge for this). Otherwise, you will be assigned a new IP every time you connect to the internet.

If your ISP modem is connected to a router first and then to the computer, you have to log in to your router settings and forward incoming http requests. This is usually done by putting a forwarding rule for incoming TCP connections on port 80. You have to forward these connections to port 80 on your computer. If you also want to support https, you have to forward port 443.

Comment: 10 year (almost 11 in 1 day) later, you have helped me host a site that I made for my wife. Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, actually you can. If you are connected to the internet directly (meaning no router in the middle doing NAT) you can just use your public IP and make sure your firewall rules allow that traffic to pass.

If you are behind a router then you'll have to probably write forwarding rules to your machine in your LAN. Additionally, if you don't want to be worrying about IPs then you can use [No-IP](http://www.no-ip.com/) and the like.

Comment: can you please tell me using proces of [No-Ip](http://www.no-ip.com/) ?

Comment: i did everything right in the configuration but i didnt have port forwarding ( and i didnt know about it ). talkings to the network people actually solved my problem because i needed forwarding.